# Transpose a List of Lists

Tags: r

I have a list which contains list entries, and I need to transpose the structure.
The original structure is rectangular, but the names in the sub-lists do not match.

Here is an example:

```
ax <- data.frame(a=1,x=2)
ay <- data.frame(a=3,y=4)
bw <- data.frame(b=5,w=6)
bz <- data.frame(b=7,z=8)
before <- list(  a=list(x=ax, y=ay),   b=list(w=bw, z=bz))
```

What I want:

```
after  <- list(w.x=list(a=ax, b=bw), y.z=list(a=ay, b=bz))
```

I do not care about the names of the resultant list (at any level).

Clearly this can be done explicitly:

```
after <- list(x.w=list(a=before$a$x, b=before$b$w), y.z=list(a=before$a$y, b=before$b$z))
```

but this is ugly and only works for a 2x2 structure.  What's the idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: You can transpose a data frame `d` by collecting the rows, say, with `apply(d, 1L, identity)`. So try coercing `before` into a data frame; one way to do that would be with `tibble::as_tibble()`, from the tibble package. That said, using `purrr::transpose()`, as @alistaire suggested, is faster than using base R's `apply()`. (It's implemented in C.)

Comment: @egnha Not possible here.  The list entries themselves are data frames.

Comment: Try it with `d <- tibble::as_tibble(before)`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following piece of code will create a list with i-th element of every list in `before`:

```
lapply(before, "[[", i)
```

Now you just have to do

```
n <- length(before[[1]]) # assuming all lists in before have the same length
lapply(1:n, function(i) lapply(before, "[[", i))
```

and it should give you what you want. It's not very efficient (travels every list many times), and you can probably make it more efficient by keeping pointers to current list elements, so please decide whether this is good enough for you.

Comment: I'd replace `1:n` with `seq_along(before[[1]])` but otherwise, this will work fine.  The lists may not always be 2x2, but they won't be big (the data frame are large, however).

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why do you like the `seq_along` version better? Is it just the expressiveness? (I understand that performance-wise, it's the same).

Comment: That, and it doesn't return wrong results if the length is 0.

Comment: Length 0 is a great point, haven't thought about that before.

Answer (score 14):

The `purrr` package now makes this process really easy:

```
library(purrr)

before %>% transpose()

## $x
## $x$a
##   a x
## 1 1 2
## 
## $x$b
##   b w
## 1 5 6
## 
## 
## $y
## $y$a
##   a y
## 1 3 4
## 
## $y$b
##   b z
## 1 7 8
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a different idea - use the fact that `data.table` can store `data.frame`'s (in fact, given your question, maybe you don't even need to work with lists of lists and could just work with `data.table`'s):

```
library(data.table)

dt = as.data.table(before)
after = as.list(data.table(t(dt)))
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach.  I've done some investigating on `data.table`, but haven't used it nearly enough.

Comment: This doesn't actually require data.table `as.list(data.frame(do.call(rbind, before)))` will work as well.

Answer (score 3):

While this is an old question, i found it while searching for the same problem, and the [second hit on google](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/transpose-lists-td4660695.html) had a much more elegant solution in my opinion:

```
list_of_lists <- list(a=list(x="ax", y="ay"), b=list(w="bw", z="bz"))
new <- do.call(rbind, list_of_lists)
```

`new` is now a rectangular structure, a strange object: A list with a dimension attribute. It works with as many elements as you wish, as long as every sublist has the same length. To change it into a more common R-Object, one could for example create a matrix like this:

```
new.dims <- dim(new)
matrix(new,nrow = new.dims[1])
```

`new.dims` needed to be saved, as the `matrix()` function deletes the attribute of the list. Another way:

```
new <- do.call(c, new) 
dim(new) <- new.dims
```

You can now for example convert it into a data.frame with `as.data.frame()` and split it into columns or do column wise operations. Before you do that, you could also change the `dim` attribute of the matrix, if it fits your needs better.

Comment: Except it gives deceiving results.  All matrix elements are lists

Comment: Hmm, not quite but similar. The result is a list of 4 single character elements (True matrices can only contain atomic types) with a dimension attribute. But depending on the use case, this is not that bad, it just needs to be converted to a "true" matrix. I will edit my solution to reflect that.

Comment: `rbind` on the list of lists is a solid idea.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself with this problem but I needed a solution that kept the names of each element. The solution I came up with should also work when the sub lists are not all the same length.

```
invertList = function(l){
  elemnames = NULL
  for (i in seq_along(l)){
    elemnames = c(elemnames, names(l[[i]]))
  }

  elemnames = unique(elemnames)

  res = list()
  for (i in seq_along(elemnames)){
    res[[elemnames[i]]] = list()
    for (j in seq_along(l)){
      if(exists(elemnames[i], l[[j]], inherits = F)){
        res[[i]][[names(l)[j]]] = l[[names(l)[j]]][[elemnames[i]]]
      }
    }
  }
  res
}
```