# How to assign multiple columns to data.frame without repeating function call

Tags: r, dataframe

Why doesn't this work for an example? There's same value in each row and warning as well

```
data <- data.frame(id = 1:10)
slowCall <- function(id) data.frame(b = rep(id, 3), c = runif(3))
data[,c("d", "e")] <- sapply(data$id, function(id) {
 tmp <- slowCall(id)
 list(sum(tmp$b), min(tmp$c))
})

Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , c("d", "e"), value = list(3L, 0.104784948984161,  :
 provided 20 variables to replace 2 variables
print(data)
   id d         e
1   1 3 0.1047849
2   2 3 0.1047849
3   3 3 0.1047849
4   4 3 0.1047849
5   5 3 0.1047849
6   6 3 0.1047849
7   7 3 0.1047849
8   8 3 0.1047849
9   9 3 0.1047849
10 10 3 0.1047849
```

Comment: it does "work" just not the way you would like it to work.  It is working exactly as it _should_ work ;)     Have a search throgh stackoverflow for `[r] data.table`

Comment: I was looking for how to do it especially with data.frame instead of data.table. I'm also not saying that it should work as I expected but I would like to understand why I'm getting results looking like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. First, vectorize the `assign` function (per @Joran's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520163/2338862)), then modify your code slightly.

```
# vectorize
assignVec <- Vectorize("assign",c("x","value"))

library(plyr)
set.seed(1) # this is just here for reproducibility

data <- data.frame(id = 1:10)
slowCall <- function(id) data.frame(b = rep(id, 3), c = runif(3))

# I store this as `tmp` just to make the code below look cleaner
tmp <- mlply(sapply(data$id, function(id) {
    tmp <- slowCall(id)
    list(sum(tmp$b), min(tmp$c))
}), c)

# here's the key part:
data <- within(data, assignVec(c('d','e'), tmp, envir=environment()))
```

Output:

```
> data
   id          e  d
1   1 0.26550866  3
2   2 0.20168193  6
3   3 0.62911404  9
4   4 0.06178627 12
5   5 0.38410372 15
6   6 0.49769924 18
7   7 0.38003518 21
8   8 0.12555510 24
9   9 0.01339033 27
10 10 0.34034900 30
```

Note: I invoke `plyr::mlply` to get your `sapply` output into a list.

The simpler answer, though, is to change the righthand side of your operation into:

```
data[,c("d", "e")] <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(data$id, function(id) {
 tmp <- slowCall(id)
 list(sum(tmp$b), min(tmp$c))
})))
```

which would give you the same result.

Comment: Why transposing is needed in this? When assigning a single column for example it populates it without transposing just fine. I thought apply family of functions translate roughly to map function found in functional languages but returning list or vector seems to be some kind of special case here.

Comment: @user2908955 Take a look at the output of your `sapply` call when it contains only return value versus two. Your current output is a matrix, which has to be coerced to fit into your dataframe correctly, whereas with one return value, it is simply a vector that will be added as a column quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the matrix returned by your `sapply` contains one-element lists instead of numeric values. Change your `list` to a `c` and transpose the output, then it will work.

```
data[, c("d", "e")] <- t(sapply(data$id, function(id) {
  tmp <- slowCall(id)
  c(sum(tmp$b), min(tmp$c))
}))
```

Comment: This one coerces both data to common type

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic method to add two columns of different data types (e.g. character and numeric). It uses lists and transposes lists (via [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16179574/697568)).

Here, this answer would preserve the integer and numeric types of the two outputs.

```
rowwise <- lapply(data$id, function(id) {
  tmp <- slowCall(id)
  list(sum(tmp$b), min(tmp$c))
})
colwise <- lapply(seq_along(rowwise[[1]]), function(i) lapply(rowwise, "[[", i))

data[,c("d", "e")] <- colwise
```