# Populate 2 dataframe columns simultaneously?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe and each row has up to 4 different pairs of geographic coordinates.  The fields that hold them are LAT1 & LONG1, LAT2 & LONG2, LAT3 & LONG3 and LAT4 & LONG4.  These vary in completeness - and often some values are NA.  I want to create columns "LAT" and "LONG", and populate these columns with the first **pair** of coordinates in which neither is NA.  The order I check will be 1, 2, 3, 4.  For example, my data might look like this:

```
ORD LAT1 LONG1     LAT2     LONG2     LAT3     LONG3     LAT4     LONG4
1   NA   NA       NA        NA        44.65783 -65.86633 44.68800 -65.80183
2   NA   NA       NA        NA        44.67033 -65.81833 44.67333 -65.84767
3   NA   NA       44.19133  -63.32017 44.25583 -63.27117 NA        NA
4   NA   NA       44.25717  NA        44.30950 -63.18617 NA        NA
5   NA   NA       44.30667  -63.17550 44.35483 -63.08717 NA        NA
6   NA   NA       44.35433  -63.07267 44.30633 -63.12117 NA        NA
```

and I want to end up with this:

```
ORD LAT1 LONG1     LAT2     LONG2     LAT3     LONG3     LAT4     LONG4      LAT       LONG
1   NA   NA       NA        NA        44.65783 -65.86633 44.68800 -65.80183  44.65783  -65.86633
2   NA   NA       NA        NA        44.67033 -65.81833 44.67333 -65.84767  44.67033  -65.81833
3   NA   NA       44.19133  -63.32017 44.25583 -63.27117 NA        NA        44.19133  -63.32017
4   NA   NA       44.25717  NA        44.30950 -63.18617 NA        NA        44.30950  -63.18617
5   NA   NA       44.30667  -63.17550 44.35483 -63.08717 NA        NA        44.30667  -63.17550
6   NA   NA       44.35433  -63.07267 44.30633 -63.12117 NA        NA        44.35433  -63.07267
```

I have actually already achieved this through the following 2 `ifelse` blocks, and they are doing exactly what I want:

```
set_df$LAT <- ifelse(is.na(set_df$LAT1) | is.na(set_df$LONG1),
                      ifelse(is.na(set_df$LAT2) | is.na(set_df$LONG2),
                          ifelse(is.na(set_df$LAT3) | is.na(set_df$LONG3), set_df$LAT4,set_df$LAT3),
                      set_df$LAT2),
                  set_df$LAT1)
set_df$LONG <- ifelse(is.na(set_df$LAT1) | is.na(set_df$LONG1),
                         ifelse(is.na(set_df$LAT2) | is.na(set_df$LONG2),
                                ifelse(is.na(set_df$LAT3) | is.na(set_df$LONG3), set_df$LONG4,set_df$LONG3),
                         set_df$LONG2),
                   set_df$LONG1)
```

So the reason I'm here is that this strikes me as an inefficient way to get my results since I'm essentially identifying the pair of coordinates that I want twice - the first block is capturing only the LAT and the second block grabs the LONG.

Is there a way I can grab both values and pop them into the new columns at once? I would vastly prefer only base R solutions.

**edit:**
Here it is using @user2974951's method, but with named fields and desired output:

```
    tmp=apply(set_df,1,function(x){
      if (!is.na(x["LAT1"]) & !is.na(x["LONG1"])) {return(c(x[test1="LAT1"],x["LONG1"]))}
      else if (!is.na(x["LAT2"]) & !is.na(x["LONG2"])) {return(c(x["LAT2"],x["LONG2"]))}
      else if (!is.na(x["LAT3"]) & !is.na(x["LONG3"])) {return(c(x["LAT3"],x["LONG3"]))}
      else {return(c(x["LAT4"],x["LONG4"]))}
    })
    set_df = cbind(set_df,t(tmp))
    colnames(set_df)[colnames(set_df)=="1"] <- "LAT"
    colnames(set_df)[colnames(set_df)=="2"] <- "LONG"
```

Comment: Would a solution using loops be acceptable?

Comment: For assigning multiple columns try techniques like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528836/how-to-assign-multiple-columns-to-data-frame-without-repeating-function-call

Comment: @user2974951 - I'm open to it, but given that I'm trying to make the code more efficient, I'm not sure that would work any better?

Comment: @anotherfred - thanks!  On that page you linked to, I liked the response given by Oscar de León too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution using apply

```
tmp=apply(dat,1,function(x){
  if (!is.na(x[2]) & !is.na(x[3])) {return(c(x[2],x[3]))}
  else if (!is.na(x[4]) & !is.na(x[5])) {return(c(x[4],x[5]))}
  else if (!is.na(x[6]) & !is.na(x[7])) {return(c(x[6],x[7]))}
  else {return(c(x[8],x[9]))}
})

cbind(dat,t(tmp))

  ORD LAT1 LONG1     LAT2     LONG2     LAT3     LONG3     LAT4     LONG4        1         2
1   1   NA    NA       NA        NA 44.65783 -65.86633 44.68800 -65.80183 44.65783 -65.86633
2   2   NA    NA       NA        NA 44.67033 -65.81833 44.67333 -65.84767 44.67033 -65.81833
3   3   NA    NA 44.19133 -63.32017 44.25583 -63.27117       NA        NA 44.19133 -63.32017
4   4   NA    NA 44.25717        NA 44.30950 -63.18617       NA        NA 44.30950 -63.18617
5   5   NA    NA 44.30667 -63.17550 44.35483 -63.08717       NA        NA 44.30667 -63.17550
6   6   NA    NA 44.35433 -63.07267 44.30633 -63.12117       NA        NA 44.35433 -63.07267
```