# Data Subsetting: Lists within list in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a list containing 100 lists within it, each of which has 552 numerical values. How do I sequentially extract the 1st value (and so on up to 552) from each of the 100 lists?

Example: 5 lists within a list containing the numbers 1-10

```
list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

I want to extract each term sequentially i.e. 1,1,1,1,1 and then
2,2,2,2,2 and so on

Comment: Can you give a small example (say a 10th of your actual data) with an indication of the output you expect too.

Comment: you can iterate over a list by key, and then iterate the object of inner list.

Comment: Something like this question perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179197/transpose-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement produces a list of vectors, taking the first element of each of your original vectors, the second element, etc., giving `NA` for the value of a short vector:

```
num <-  max(unlist(lapply(x, length)))  ## Length of the longest vector in x

lapply(seq(num), function(i) unlist(lapply(x, `[`, i)))
```

And here's a matrix approach:

```
matrix(unlist(x), ncol=length(x))
```

The rows of that matrix are your elements.  This relies on each vector being the same length.

Comment: Cheers Matthew - I was being supremely daft; converting to a matrix solved all my problems!!!